# Only one user get HttpContext Null error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I asked same question in Asp.Net Core [forum](https://forums.asp.net/p/2144161/6219259.aspx?p=True&t=636679268825959448), but would like to ask StackOverflow geeks too

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.1 web application running on Windows Server 2008 R2.
Everyone have access to this web app but only one person gets "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." for HttpContext

Weird is, he can access the same application that running on test server which is same Windows Server 2008 R2

I indicated the line where error out by "**<--------**" in Session class code.

I spent many days to fix it, but no luck yet.

Here is my Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup {
static public IConfigurationRoot Global { get; set; }
    public IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration) {
        try
        {
            HostingEnvironment = env;
            Configuration = configuration;
            this.SetGlobals(HostingEnvironment);
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //If failed in here, it needs special error handler
            Helper.errorMsg msg = new Helper.errorMsg();
            Helper.CreateRfs_LostHosting(ex, -1, msg).Wait();
        }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.AddSession(options => {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
        });
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseBrowserLink();
    } else {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes => {
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

        Session.Configure(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>());
}
```

}

I have a Session Class:

```
public class Session
{
    private static IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public static void Configure(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public static void Initialize() {
        var sessionUser = Session.GetSessionObj<SessionUser>("SessionUser");
        if (sessionUser == null) {
            sessionUser = new SessionUser();
            sessionUser.Initialize(HttpContext); <--------------------HttpContext Null error
            Session.SetSessionObj("SessionUser", sessionUser);
        }
    }

    public static HttpContext HttpContext { get { return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext; } }
    public static SessionUser SessionUser { get { return Session.GetSessionObj<SessionUser>("SessionUser"); } }

    public static bool UserValidated { get {
            if (SessionUser == null)
            {
                Initialize();
            }
            return SessionUser.Validated;
        } }


    public static void SetSessionVar(string key, string value) {
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString(key, value);
    }

    public static void SetSessionObj(string key, object value) {
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetObject(key, value);
    }

    public static T GetSessionObj<T>(string key) {
        var sessionObj = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetObject<T>(key);
        return sessionObj;
    }
}
```

here is SessionUser class:

```
public class SessionUser
{
public void Initialize(HttpContext httpContext) {
    string userName = null;
    var identity = httpContext.User.Identity;

    if (identity.IsAuthenticated) {
        userName = identity.Name;
    } else {
        var basicCredentials = new BasicAuthenticationHeader(httpContext);
        userName = basicCredentials.UserName;
    }
    }
}
```